# Reorder 3 columns on Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: multiple-columns, bootstrap-4

I have a problem similar to this one - [Bootstrap: reorder 3 columns on small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048746/bootstrap-reorder-3-columns-on-small-screens)

The solution proposed there was quite acceptable, but on the latest version of Bootstrap it does not work. Can I do this in the current version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) in Bootstrap.

There are classes `order-1` to `order-12`.

There are also responsive classes, so you can do something like:

Div A: `order-2`

Div B: `order-3 order-md-1`

This will result in:

**Smaller screens**: A B

**Bigger screens**: B A

Comment: Thank you, I know about order classes. But I could not stick block C to the right block A. I found another solution - https://www.codeply.com/go/cftRvGUEeP

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in bootstrap 4, because grid is based on flex. However, a solution can be created using `display: contents` and `order: -1`.

I've already shared full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394907/409102